# Is there a way to execute settimeout with 1s before settimeout with time 0s

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log('a')
console.log("b")
setTimeout(() => console.log('c'), 2000);
setTimeout(() => console.log('d'), 0);
```

This will give output 'a b d c'. Is there any way by using anything but not by changing the value to get output  'a b c d'?

Can it be done with a promise or callback, or is there any easy way we have?

Comment: settimeout inside settimeout?

Comment: for info : correct syntax is `setTimeout(console.log, 2000,'c');`

Comment: @MisterJojo OP's syntax isnt wrong?

Comment: @MisterJojo ah, correct spelling of opinions is onions

Comment: @cmgchess  no, it is possible, but it remains incorrect, because it superimposes a function on top of a function. there is a saying: why make it simple when you can make it complicated?

Comment: @MoritzRingler no, it is not an opinion, it is a reality

Comment: @MisterJojo No, it's an onion. In jest, of course. I value that you point out a different way of writing it. But it is not the "correct" way to do it. There are other factors, mainly readability in this case. Or really just taste. There are people who would mark your version in a review with a note to the principal of least astonishment. And that's a reality, too, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @MoritzRingler call it an onion if you want... I agree with you that there will always be a thousand ways to write and say anything, some will be shocking to others, and can lead to burning alive someone (requiescant in pace Giordano Bruno). I have only indicated a small verifiable fact here, without passing judgment on anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a setTimeout outside the setTimeout of 'd'

```js
console.log('a')
console.log("b")
setTimeout(()=>{

  setTimeout(() => console.log('d'), 0);

},2000)
setTimeout(() => console.log('c'), 2000);
```